# Nginx not responding from outside the remote box

Tags: nginx, openssl, gunicorn, firewall, ufw

My website (Django/nginx/gunicorn/mysql) which is hosted on a remote box was working fine, until I decided to restart remote box for some reason. So after the restart, in the remote box when I say `curl -IL -H -GET my.web.address` it works fine. However, when I try the same command from outside, it reports `curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to my.web.address`.

Any help is appreciated. Please find below the relevant things which I checked for.

I'm using a CentOS 7 system. I predominantly used [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-centos-7)

### nginx is listening on the right ports

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3425/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3425/nginx: master
```

### Firewall (see ufw result) is allowing my ports

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp (SSH)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
224.0.0.251 5353/udp (mDNS) ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
22/tcp (SSH (v6))          ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
ff02::fb 5353/udp (mDNS)   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
22 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
80 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
443 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

### sestatus

`SELinux status:                 disabled`

### Output of `nmap` to check the port status

```
nmap -sT my.ip.address

PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
111/tcp  open  rpcbind
443/tcp  open  https
3306/tcp open  mysql
```

### Content of the `nginx.conf`

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

### server blocks of my `nginx.conf`

```
server {
    server_name my.ip.address my.web.address;
    error_log /srv/www/myweb/logs/error.log;
    access_log /srv/www/myweb/logs/access.log;
    charset utf-8;

    location /static/{
        alias /srv/www/myweb/latestRelease/mywebDB/app/src/static/;
    }

    location /{
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/srv/www/myweb/latestRelease/mywebDB/mywebdb.sock;
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.web.address/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.web.address/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = my.ip.address) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = my.web.address) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

      listen 80;
      server_name my.ip.address my.web.address;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

I've checked my sock file permissions, they are spinning up correctly by the respective user. The file permissions are set correctly.

### contents of the `gunicorn.service` file

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=user
Group=nginx
WorkingDirectory=/srv/www/myweb/latestRelease/mywebDB/app/src
ExecStart=/srv/www/myweb/latestRelease/mywebDB/app/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/srv/www/myweb/latestRelease/mywebDB/mywebdb.sock app.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Meanwhile, just to ensure my issues are not related to Lets encrypt server certificates, I made changes in my `nginx.conf` to work only HTTP.

Below are the output of `curl -IL -GET my.domain.name` when I ran it on my remote box:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.17.9
Date: Fri, 06 Mar 2020 08:26:42 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 7918
Connection: keep-alive
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

I get the same output as above while running with the IP address.

When I ran the curl from my laptop I get the `curl: (52) Empty reply from server` as the response with both domain name, and IP address.

I pinged the server (both using IP, and domain name) from my laptop, and they send/receive packets. The domain name is rightly mapped with the IP. I also validated it using `nslookup`

Since I disabled the HTTPS, the TLS versions doesn't matter isn't it?

Additionally, I disabled the firewall using ufw. The, I looked up the `iptables -L` rules. I'm a newbie in this area, but to me it seems like the results of the remote server are designed to accept any incoming connections.

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the problem is fixed!

The problem was that somehow, UFW rules didn't update the iptables entry to allow the ports 80/443.

I modified it manually with the below commands.

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```